# Conectarse a la API de google calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando Conectarme a la **API de Google Calendar**

```
const API_KEY = "AIzaSyACg6feWvXYw_czwB7yYZxr2HFZw8Wjd9k"

  axios({
    method:'get',
    url:`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=${API_KEY}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${response.credential.accessToken}`
    }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
  });
```

pero me da este error

```
error
:
{errors: [{domain: "global", reason: "insufficientPermissions", message: "Insufficient Permission"}],…}
code
:
403
errors
:
[{domain: "global", reason: "insufficientPermissions", message: "Insufficient Permission"}]
message
:
"Insufficient Permission"
```

Comment: Hay una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978192/google-plus-api-insufficientpermissions-error) en SO, en la que comentan que hay el problema es el "access token" que posiblemente no cubra todo el "scope" necesario, quizá te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución que me sirvió para crear eventos con React.JS

```
const CLIENT_ID = 'tu id'
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";// permisos

script.onload = () => {
  gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {

      if(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get() != true) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

       let request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'resource': newEvent
        });

        request.execute(function(event) {
          console.log('evento creado:', event)
        })

    });
  });
};
```